# Create a Regex using MarcEdit

Tags: regex, replace, find

I need help with regular expression. I want to add parenthesis () to my data $q if missing in the text, but ignore adding parenthesis if already have it. There is no space after $q, and some characters may contain periods in the end.

I need the regex to Find characters (this is an example so that the wording will vary):

$qpaperback

$q(hardbound)

$qpbk.

And Replace them to the following, but ignore adding parenthesis if not missing the ():

$q(paperback)

$q(hardbound)   --this one already had a parenthesis, so it was ignore.

$q(pbk.)

Any help will be graciously received

Comment: Try `(\$q)(?!\()(\S+)` https://regex101.com/r/JPxsrb/1 or `(\$q)(\w+\.?)(?:\s|$)` https://regex101.com/r/GjI8kK/1 and in the replacement use the 2 capturing groups `$1($2)`

Answer (score 0):

If lookarounds are supported, then maybe,

```
(?<=\$q)(?=[^(])(.*)
```

and a replacement of,

```
($1)
```

might be somewhat close.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/SazHXS/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/SazHXS/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---